# How to set up mic volume to a fixed level

Tags: system-settings, macos, microphone, google-hangouts

Lately, I am holding a lot of vconfs on Google Hangouts. I'm using a headphone set but the internal mic is capturing the input sound. Apparently, if I move a bit away from my iMac or if I speak softer, the system increases (adjusts) that volume automatically. That is all very nice except that then, I start hearing my own echo on the other end! (I mean, transmitted back to me from my vconf partner amplified and delayed).

Does anybody know of a way to prevent that (automatic) behaviour? For instance, to limit the volume instead of just setting it up.

Comment: If you are getting the echo back from the person you are chatting with, then the problem is most likely on their end. They likely have there speakers too close to their mic and/or no echo reducing features. There isn't much *you* can probably do about this. They have to fix it.

Comment: That's what I thought but the effect is directly proportional to my mic's volume. BTW, my partner was using headphones with built-in mic and an echo-cancellation feature (if you can believe the maker, I mean).

Comment: Is there a natural echo in the room you are in?

Comment: Nope. Too small a room for that ;-) Besides, I do work with my headphones on and I do hear the echo as amplified, with an electronic quality to it.

Comment: Anyway, even without the echo, mine was also a question on how to configure mic's volume, especially, on how to limit its volume/preventing the automatic increasing by the OS

Comment: The OS doesn't automatically increase the volume of the mic, however some applications do. I haven't used Google Hangouts much, but I know Skype has this feature as an option. You may want to check the application preferences.